# Xsl transformation cuts space between two <xsl:value-of select's

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I've got the following line within my xsl file:

```
   network <xsl:value-of select="/config/areas/inside/network"/>&#32;<xsl:value-of select="/config/areas/inside/subnetmask"/>
```

My transformation code in C#:

```
        XPathDocument xPathDoc = new XPathDocument(xmlPath);
        //XslTransform xslTrans = new XslTransform(); -> Deprecated!
        XslCompiledTransform xslTrans = new XslCompiledTransform();

        XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("config.cfg", Encoding.UTF8);

        xslTrans.Load(xslPath);

        xslTrans.Transform(xPathDoc, null, writer);

        writer.Close();
```

With the deprecated version everything works fine (after I placed the ASCII code for a space between the two elements), but the XslCompiledTransform class has some other normalization algorithms in it and I don't know how to avoid this behavior.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is "everything works fine" and what is "this behavior"? Please, provide the output of the XSLT transformation and state what is the problem... Defining your question in an understandable way is the first, and quite obvious suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, your problem here is that when you put `&#32;` in an XML document, this is technically no different to entering an ordinary space, and hence the XML parser treats it as whitespace.

I would suggest changing that line to

`<xsl:value-of select="concat('network ',/config/areas/inside/network,' ',/config/areas/inside/subnetmask)" />`

By enclosing the space within a concat function like this, it's not sitting in the XML document as a node on it's own, and won't be mistaken for irrelevant whitespace.

Not related to your problem, but I'd also recommend wrapping the `XmlTextWriter` in a using block:

```
using (XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("config.cfg", Encoding.UTF8))
{
    xslTrans.Load(xslPath);
    xslTrans.Transform(xPathDoc, null, writer);
}
```

It automatically handles the disposing of the writer properly.

Comment: Nice, I'll try it soon and mark your answer as accepted if it worked. Should I call writer.Close() if I am using the using statement or does the dispose handle that for me too?

Comment: @tkrause There is no need to close the writer when using the `using` statement - the dispose handles all cleanup.

Comment: Brilliant, I am not really familiar with xslt and it's methods and commands. Thank you! :)